# URL rewriting in address bar

Tags: browser

I have no idea where to find out about why if I paste this url into the address bar of Chrome, Safari, and Firefox it will be translated into a different URL with a couple of accented characters.

It results in a crypto currency phishing site so beware.

I'm trying to find the logic (javascript) or whatever that causes this translation

The base url is http://www.xn--shapehit-ez9c7y.com

I apologise if this is the wrong site to ask the question on.

Answer (score 2):

This is called **[PunyCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)**, which is a way to represent Unicode within the ASCII character set. This allows websites to have names with foreign characters, such as in Chinese or Arabic. While this is incredibly useful, it can also be used for deceptive impersonation (often maliciously, as noted in your question).

Different browsers treat PunyCode differently. For example, Safari and Edge will **not** attempt to covert PunyCode, and will show the full 'strange' URLs.

However, **[according to Sophos](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2017/04/19/phishing-with-punycode-when-foreign-letters-spell-english-words/)**,

> Chrome and Firefox won’t automatically decode punycode URLs if they mix multiple alphabets or languages, on the grounds that such text strings are highly unlikely in real life and therefore suspicious. But both Chrome and Firefox will autoconvert punycode URLs that contain all their characters in the same language.

A security researcher called Xudong Zheng actually registered the domain `xn--80ak6aa92e.com`, which translates to `аррӏе` in 'Russian'. When visited in Chrome or Firefox, it looks identical to `apple.com` in the URL:

[image]

Fortunately his site simply warns of this forgery, but it could easily have been used maliciously.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: A stellar answer. SO needs more of you ;)

Comment: Agreed with @vzwick. Stellar answer. I am upvoting it. Thank you from more than 6 years after your OP.